# Why does a single-threaded execution of a heavy Polars expression run faster than a multi-threaded one?

Tags: windows, optimization, python-polars

Surprisingly, Polars >= 0.17.13 performs better, if allowed to use only 1 thread. For some lower Polars versions there is no difference.

```py
# polars>=0.17.3

import polars as pl
import time
import os


def compute(initial_value: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    """Waste some CPU power to compute the golden ratio"""
    result = initial_value
    for i in range(100):
        result = (1 + result) ** 0.5
    return result


# Block parallel execution of polars expressions
os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = "1"  # the more - the slower

# Create a dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame(pl.repeat(0.0, 10_000_000, eager=True).alias("value"))

# Compute
start_time = time.perf_counter()
df_b = (
    df.lazy().with_columns(compute(pl.col("value")).alias("result")).collect()
)
delta_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
print(f"Thread pool size: {pl.threadpool_size()}. Time: {delta_time:.3f} s.")
```

Below are results with and without `os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = "1"`.

```
Thread pool size: 1. Time: 2.102 s.
Thread pool size: 16. Time: 3.634 s.
```

Comment: Possibly lazy() serializes operations and multiple threads is bad for serialized operations.

Comment: Lazy doesn't serialize anything. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable `POLARS_MAX_THREADS` doesn't have any effect if you set that after polars is imported. So your example should run the same, no matter what the value is.

### Expression parallelism

Polars' expression parallelism is very lightweight for arithmetic, they have little overhead and little contention. I also cannot reproduce your example:

```
Thread pool size: 1. Time: 32.399 s.
Thread pool size: 16. Time: 29.662 s.
```

On my machine a thread pool of size 1 is slightly slower.

### Recursive expression

Your example uses an expression that is recursive. That means there is little to no parallelism to exploit, as we need the previous result before we can compute the next.

This is also visible in thread utilization. On my machine this expression can only use ~3 threads on ~30%.

### Real world expression

I'd encourage you to benchmark your actual query. Computing a highly recursive golden ratio very likely doesn't reflect your data use case. The conclusions you make here don't map onto most real world problems as most expression are not highly recursive.

Comment: Looks like the effect manifests on Windows 10 but not on Linux Mint 20.1 on the same machine. So I've added the `windows` tag.
Somehow `os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = "1"` has effect even after `import polars`, at least on Windows.
I've used a recursive expression intentionally to prevent polars from using multiple threads (as I thought).  However, as you pointed out polars still uses several threads.
My thoughts were: if polars can run faster in this case, then this behavior could be made a default and make polars better eventually.

Comment: It is not really possible that POLARS_MAX_THREADS after import has effect. The behavior you observe, must be caused by something else. 

Does your device maybe throttle on the second run?

Comment: I've just tested my real world polars-based code (which benefits greatly from parallelization) with and without `os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = "1"` after `import polars as pl` on my Windows and Linux 2-core laptop, as well as on my virtual Windows  8-core workstation. All 3 platforms show the same result: limiting thread count to 1 slows down execution about 2 and 8 times respectively.
Also with `os.environ["POLARS_MAX_THREADS"] = "1000"` in debug mode I can see in Windows task manager, that the total number of threads goes up by 1000 right after the first `df = pl.DataFrame()`.